# DAX - get average of last month

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can get average of last month, I tried with this but it doesn't work out:
calculate (tablename[price],filter(tablename,max(tablename[date]))

Comment: Can you show us example data from your table?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `AVERAGEX`?

```
Average Last Month =
AVERAGEX (
    FILTER ( tablename, tablename[date] = MAX ( tablename[date] ) ),
    tablename[price]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( table[price] ),
    PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Date'[Date] )
)
```

Remember you need a Date table in your model in order to use time intelligence functions in DAX.